# Generate identical pdf files with iText given the same code and data

Tags: java, pdf, itext

I'm trying out iText in java and I noticed that generating separate pdfs using the same code and data produces files that have the same content but are binary different.
By comparing them as text, one obvious difference is a timestamp in the file.
Additionally though I see a number of small differences in metadata that I am unable to interpret.

Is there a way to generate identical files given the same java code and input data?

Comment: *Is there a way to generate identical files given the same java code and input data?* - please be aware that the time of creation is part of the input data. Thus, it is extremely difficult to really supply the same input data.

Comment: By design, you should never be able to create two identical PDFs using the same code. I'm talking about ISO-32000-1, not about iText. It seems that you want to create a digital signature to ensure the integrity of the file. If so, why would you "roll your own system"? Why not use the concept of digital signatures to meet your requirement?

Comment: I was thinking more about finding redundant documents using checksums, but I understand it's not possible by design. Thanks Bruno.